# Susy and device-pixel-ratio

Tags: susy-compass

I haven't seen anything about this in Susy's documentation, but is there a means for adding device pixel ratio to Susy's generated media queries? Or is this something that requires customizing the at-breakpoint mixin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Susy's `at-breakpoint` is really just a shortcut for the simplest mix/max media-queries. For more powerful media-queries, I recommend the [breakpoint plugin](https://github.com/Team-Sass/breakpoint). You can use that in conjunction with Susy's `layout` mixin to re-create the `at-breakpoint` effect:

```
@include breakpoint($your-advanced-media-queries) {
  @include layout($your-desired-column-count) {
    // your styles
  }
}
```